# C getline() - how to deal with buffers / how to read unknown number of values into array

Tags: c, getline

First of all, some background: I'm trying to get in a list of integers from an external file and put them into an array. I am using getline to parse the input file line by line:

```
int lines = 0;
size_t * inputBuffer = (size_t *) malloc(sizeof(size_t));
char * storage = NULL;
```

I am calling getline like so:

```
getline(&storage, &s, input)
```

I heard from the man page on getline that if you provide a size_t * buffer, you can have getline resize it for you when it exceeds the byte allocation. My question is, what can you use this buffer for? Will it contain all of the items that you read with getline()? Is it simpler to read from this buffer, or to traverse the input in a different way when putting these integers into an array? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The buffer will only contain the *last* line you read with `getline`. The purpose is just to take a little bit of the effort of managing memory off your code.

What will happen if you repeatedly call `getline`, passing it the same buffer repeatedly, is that the buffer will expand to the length of the longest line in your file and stay there. Each call will replace its contents with the next line's.

You're not providing it a `size_t*`, you're giving it a `char*`.

Comment: Oh ok, I see now. So then is it possible to use getline() to iterate through the input once and count the number of lines, and then use getline to pass through once again and store the values into a malloc'ed array?

Comment: @theeggman85 If you `fseek` back to the start of the file (or close it and then open it again), yes. You could also use a linked list or other dynamically-growing structure to only need one pass.

Answer (score 13):

This is not the correct use of `getline`. I strongly suggest to read *carefully* its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man//3/getline).

You could have some code like

```
FILE *inputfile=fopen("yourinput.txt", "r");
size_t linesiz=0;
char* linebuf=0;
ssize_t linelen=0;
while ((linelen=getline(&linebuf, &linesiz, inputfile)>0) {
  process_line(linebuf, linesiz);
  // etc
  free(linebuf);
  linebuf=NULL;
}
```

BTW, you might (and probably should better) put

```
  free(linebuf);
  linebuf=NULL;
```

... after the `while` loop (to keep the line buffer allocated from one line to the next), and in most cases it is preferable to do so (to avoid too frequent `malloc`-s from `getline`).

Notice that [`getline` is in](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) ISO/IEC TR 24731-2:2010 extension (see [n1248](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1248.pdf)).

Comment: This is what I had basically done in my code, but my main problem is since I am getting an array whose size is unknown, I need to first go through the array and count how many lines there are. Is it possible to do this somehow?

while ((linelen=getline(&linebuf, &linesiz, inputfile)>0) {
  numOfLines ++;
}
   
for(i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++){
   addToArray();   
}

Comment: The `process_line` can actually be whatever you want. You could have a `char**linearr` pointer, and `malloc` it etc... Then use `linearr[i++] = strdup(linebuf);`

Comment: The problem I am concerned with is that when you malloc you must have a defined size, correct? And if I am both counting the elements in the array and adding them to the array in one pass, I am unsure how to get the size if I am not using something like linked lists.

Comment: But you can grow dynamically the array at runtime (by `malloc`a bigger one, then copying the content of the old variant, then `free`-ing that old variant and use the new bigger `malloc`-ated one). You definitely don't need to count lines... Just grow the array when needed!

Comment: Doesn't that take up a lot of processing time, to copy the whole array each pass through the for loop? I can definitely see that working though.

Comment: No, you are occasionally copying an array of pointers (when growing `linearr` only). You won't copy each line (only a pointer to it).