# How can I search for a specific string in a csv file, and to know in which line that string was found?

Tags: c, string, file, csv

I started to learn C and I am writing a code where the user needs to type a string he wants to search in the csv file , and if the string was found , it will print the number of line the string was found at . 
and I am not exactly sure what is the best way to do that

Comment: Please provide a minimal attempt. You probably want to use fopen to open a file, fgets to get string, count lines, and search lines. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206091/going-through-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-c

Comment: Please provide some code here first which shows an attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: This sounds like 'run `grep -n` on the CSV file'.  If that's not appropriate, you need to think about how you'll do it.  Probably open the file, read lines, keeping a count, and searching each line (and closing the file at the end).  Sounds pretty routine — `fopen()`, `fgets()`, `strstr()`, `printf()`, `fclose()`.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  — See also MCVE ([MCVE]).

Answer (score 0):

You may read line by line using [getline()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) until it returns -1 (EOF), keeping a counter on how many iterations you have done.

For each line you read, you can use [strstr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) to check if the string is present. If yes, just print the counter (that will correspond to the line).