# C program not reading characters in lines

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a text file into an array of strings, but struggling. The lines counter works correctly, but it's not making the currentLine expand, and the printf isn't printing anything in any case.

```
char* readFile() {
    FILE *fp = fopen(inputPath, "r");
    char* currentLine = "";
    char* allLines[] = {};
    int lines = 0;

    do {
        char ch = fgetc(fp);
        printf("%s", ch);
        if (ch == '\n') {
            allLines[lines] = currentLine;
            lines++;
            currentLine = "";
        } else {
            currentLine += ch;
            printf("%s", currentLine);
        }
} while (!feof(fp));



#ifdef debug
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(allLines) / sizeof(char*)); i++){
    printf("%d: %s\n", i, allLines[i]);
}
#endif


    fclose(fp);
    return lines;
}
```

Not sure what to change to fix this? inputPath is just the name of the text file for the time being.

Comment: `printf("%s", ch)` invokes undefined behaviour. use `%c` to print `char`s.

Comment: `char* allLines[] = {};` is invalid.

Comment: [`while (!feof(fp))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/10077).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Going through a text file line by line in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206091/going-through-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-c)

Comment: `currentLine += ch;` Are you trying to add a character to the end of a c-string?

Comment: @babon it would seem so.

Comment: `currentLine += ch;` -- you can't add characters to a string like that in C. Learn what a 'string' in C really is (a '\0' terminated character array that you have to define somehow, not just a pointer) Take a look at `strcpy()`, `strcat()`, `sprintf()`...

Comment: @WhozCraig Well, IMHO people coming from other (newer?) languages can be blamed for trying to append something to a c-string with `+=`. :)

Comment: Okay I fixed the string appending issue. How would I go about having an array of the strings read in correctly?

Comment: You haven't allocated any space for the current line or for the array of strings.

Comment: `return lines;` doesn't match type.

Comment: You have ask about a runtime problem.  However, you have not provided a [mcve] so your question is off topic for stack overflow