# How to save single line from file to two different strings¸in struct >> line format(NAME#SURNAME AGE)

Tags: c, file

So i have task to output to one file certain things from another file... Lets say input file is in format 
(NAME#SURNAME AGE) with 100 lines and i have to output persons that are older then 15 in this format
(NAME AGE SURNAME) and i have something like this in struct

```
struct person
{
    char name[10];
    char surname[10];
    int age;
};
```

Can I, and if I can how can I fread my input file to that struct (file is binary)

Comment: Can you post some example lines from the input? What have you tried?

Comment: Peter#Schmit 16

Comment: Jhon#Simons 9 and so on

Comment: i havent tried anything i dont have any idea how can i separate those two cause u dont have fixed number of chars in name and surname so u cant hard code it and pc sees it like one string

Comment: can you please give me short example how to do it

Comment: Ok. You read a whole line. Then you find the `#`. Them copy from the beginning of the line to the `#` character into `name`. Then you find the space in the line. You copy from after the `#` character to the space into `surname`. Then you find end of line. You convert from the next character after space to the end of line the character to a number (ex. with `atoi`). And you save the number into `age`. You can find [many examples of C online](https://www.google.com/search?q=fgets+example).

Comment: "*(file is binary)*": What do you see if you open the input file using a text editor?

Comment: well it looks crypted (wierd)... I opened it with notepad... and it is written in the task that input file is binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want more help about the code please do a first version and edit you question, then add a comment and the community will help you.**

But if you are looking for the methodology you can go with something like that :

1. Open the file you want to extract data in read mode (e.g. `fopen(filename, "r")`)
2. Check if the file was correctly open
3. Use a while and take N characters with `fgets()` or use `getline()` (Note that [`getline()`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1248.pdf) is in ISO/IEC TR 24731-2:2010 extension (see [n1248](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1248.pdf)).).
   There is lots of threads about how to read line by line in a file (e.g. [Going through a text file line by line in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206091/going-through-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-c))
4. Now you are looking for a way to split your line with delimiters, your can use `strtok()`, `strsep()`/`strpbrk()` or you can do your own implementation of a [simple string delimiter](http://source-code-share.blogspot.com/2014/07/implementation-of-java-stringsplit.html) ([Maybe look this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c))
5. Next the AGE part, you wan to only copy the line with an AGE superior to 15, so use `strtol()` to convert your string to `long int` then check the value.
   Don't use `atoi()` this function is deprecated).

   > The atoi() function has been deprecated by strtol() and should not be used in new code.

   source [Mac OS X Manual Page for atoi(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/atoi.3.html)
6. Then you need to create and/or write to a file. You can use `fopen(newFilename, "w")`, check the file descriptor the function give you in return, if it's ok you can add line with `fprintf()` (e.g. `fprintf(fd, "%s %s %s\r\n", name, age, surname);`).

If this is one of your first project/exercise in c take your time to properly understand the function you use and ***always check the returned values before using them***.