# Creating a function in C that reads a file but it infinitely loops

Tags: c

I basically want to print out all of the lines in a file i made
but then it just loops over and over back to the start
basically cuz in the function i set `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);` this part
but idk how otherwise i would place it to get through all the other lines
im basically going back to the start every time.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *freadline(FILE *fp);

int main(){

    FILE *fp = fopen("story.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error!");
    }else{
        char *pInput;
        while(!feof(fp)){
            pInput = freadline(fp);
            printf("%s\n", pInput); // outpu 
        }   
    }
    
    return 0;
}

char *freadline(FILE *fp){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; !feof(fp); i++){
        getc(fp);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // resets to origin (?)
    char *pBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*i);
    pBuffer = fgets(pBuffer, i, fp);

    return pBuffer;
}
```

this is my work so far

Comment: You will want to look at [Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) You want `rewind()` to clear `EOF`. Why do you loop with `getc()` anyway??

Comment: arpi314 Who or what text suggested `while(!feof(fp)){`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica well i want it to traverse through all the lines in the .txt file thats why i did that. Idk how to do it otherwise. Suggestions?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  well i want it to traverse through all the lines in the .txt file thats why i did that. Idk how to do it otherwise. Suggestions?

Comment: `char buffer[1024];` then `while (fgets (buffer, sizeof buffer, fp)) { /* do your stuff here */ }` (for a line-oriented read). If you want to store all lines, you will need to  return `char **` (allocate pointers, `realloc()` when you run out), then allocate for each row, copy to new allocation and assign starting address to each pointer in turn) Many, many examples already on SO.

Comment: I suggest you type `[c] read text file` into the search box at the top of this page.

Comment: you should see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9206332/12863076
it will hopefully solve your issue and clear all your doubts regarding this.

Comment: to get the size of the file, use: `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    i = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); `

Answer (score 6):

Continuing from my comments, you are thinking along the correct lines, you just haven't put the pieces together in the right order. In `main()` you are looping calling your function, allocating for a single line, and then outputting a line of text and doing it over and over again. (and without freeing any of the memory you allocate -- creating a memory leak of every line read)

If you are allocating storage to hold the line, you will generally want to read the entire file in your function in a single pass though the file allocating for, and storing all lines, and returning a pointer to your collection of lines for printing in `main()` (or whatever the calling function is).

You do that by adding one additional level of indirection and having your function return `char **`. This is a simple two-step process where you:

1. allocate a block of memory containing pointers (one pointer for each line). Since you will not know how many lines beforehand, you simply allocate some number of pointers and then `realloc()` more pointers when you run out;
2. for each line you read, you allocate `length + 1` characters of storage and copy the current line to that block of memory assigning the address for the line to your next available pointer.

(you either keep track of the number of pointers and lines allocated, or provide an additional pointer set to `NULL` as a *Sentinel* after the last pointer assigned a line -- up to you, simply keeping track with a counter is likely conceptually easier)

After reading your last line, you simply return the pointer to the collection of pointers which is assigned for use back in the caller. (you can also pass the address of a `char **` as a parameter to your function, resulting in the type being `char ***`, but being a *Three-Star Programmer* isn't always a compliment). However, there is nothing wrong with doing it that way, and in some cases, it will be required, but if you have an alternative, that is generally the preferred route.

So how would this work in practice?

Simply change your function return type to `char **` and pass an additional pointer to a counting variable so you can update the value at that address with the number of lines read before you return from your function. E.g., you could do:

```
char **readfile (FILE *fp, size_t *n);
```

Which will take your file pointer to an open file stream and then read each line from it, allocating storage for the line and assigning the address for that allocation to one of your pointers. Within the function, you would use a sufficiently sized character array to hold each line you read with `fgets()`. Trim the `'\n'` from the end and get the length and then allocate `length + 1` bytes to hold the line. Assign the address for the newly allocated block to a pointer and copy from your array to the newly allocated block.

(`strdup()` can both allocate and copy, but it is not part of the standard library, it's POSIX -- though most compilers support it as an extension if you provide the proper options)

Below the `readfile()` function puts it altogether, starting with a single pointer and reallocation twice the current number when you run out (that provides a reasonable trade-off between the number of allocations needed and the number of pointers. (after just 20 calls to `realloc()`, you would have 1M pointers). You can choose any reallocation and growth scheme you like, but you want to avoid calling `realloc()` for every line -- `realloc()` is still a relatively expensive call.

```
#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NPTR    1       /* initial no. of pointers to allocate */

/* readfile reads all lines from fp, updating the value at the address
 * provided by 'n'. On success returns pointer to allocated block of pointers
 * with each of *n pointers holding the address of an allocated block of
 * memory containing a line from the file. On allocation failure, the number
 * of lines successfully read prior to failure is returned. Caller is
 * responsible for freeing all memory when done with it.
 */
char **readfile (FILE *fp, size_t *n)
{
    char buffer[MAXC], **lines;                 /* buffer to hold each line, pointer */
    size_t allocated = NPTR, used = 0;          /* allocated and used pointers */
    
    lines = malloc (allocated * sizeof *lines); /* allocate initial pointer(s) */
    
    if (lines == NULL) {                        /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-lines");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    while (fgets (buffer, MAXC, fp)) {          /* read each line from file */
        size_t len;                             /* variable to hold line-length */
        if (used == allocated) {                /* is pointer reallocation needed */
            /* always realloc to a temporary pointer to avoid memory leak if
             * realloc fails returning NULL.
             */
            void *tmp = realloc (lines, 2 * allocated * sizeof *lines);
            if (!tmp) {                         /* validate EVERY reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-lines");
                break;                          /* lines before failure still good */
            }
            lines = tmp;                        /* assign reallocted block to lines */
            allocated *= 2;                     /* update no. of allocated pointers */
        }
        buffer[(len = strcspn (buffer, "\n"))] = 0;     /* trim \n, save length */
        
        lines[used] = malloc (len + 1);         /* allocate storage for line */
        if (!lines[used]) {                     /* validate EVERY allocation */
            perror ("malloc-lines[used]");
            break;
        }
        
        memcpy (lines[used], buffer, len + 1);  /* copy buffer to lines[used] */
        used++;                                 /* increment used no. of pointers */
    }
    *n = used;              /* update value at address provided by n */
    
    /* can do final realloc() here to resize exactly to used no. of pointers */
    
    return lines;           /* return pointer to allocated block of pointers */
}
```

In `main()`, you simply pass your file pointer and the address of a `size_t` variable and check the return before iterating through the pointers making whatever use of the line you need (they are simply printed below), e.g.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char **lines;       /* pointer to allocated block of pointers and lines */
    size_t n;           /* number of lines read */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    lines = readfile (fp, &n);
    
    if (fp != stdin)    /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    if (!lines) {       /* validate readfile() return */
        fputs ("error: no lines read from file.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {            /* loop outputting all lines read */
        puts (lines[i]);
        free (lines[i]);                        /* don't forget to free lines */
    }
    free (lines);                               /* and free pointers */
    
    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** don't forget to free the memory you allocated when you are done. That become critical when you are calling functions that allocate within other functions. In `main()`, the memory will be automatically released on exit, but build good habits.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readfile_allocate dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

The program will read any file, no matter if it has 4-lines or 400,000 lines up to the physical limit of your system memory (adjust `MAXC` if your lines are longer than 1023 characters).

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/readfile_allocate dat/captnjack.txt
==4801== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4801== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4801== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4801== Command: ./bin/readfile_allocate dat/captnjack.txt
==4801==
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
==4801==
==4801== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4801==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4801==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 5,804 bytes allocated
==4801==
==4801== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4801==
==4801== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4801== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

The full code used for the example simply includes the headers, but is included below for completeness:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NPTR    1       /* initial no. of pointers to allocate */

/* readfile reads all lines from fp, updating the value at the address
 * provided by 'n'. On success returns pointer to allocated block of pointers
 * with each of *n pointers holding the address of an allocated block of
 * memory containing a line from the file. On allocation failure, the number
 * of lines successfully read prior to failure is returned. Caller is
 * responsible for freeing all memory when done with it.
 */
char **readfile (FILE *fp, size_t *n)
{
    char buffer[MAXC], **lines;                 /* buffer to hold each line, pointer */
    size_t allocated = NPTR, used = 0;          /* allocated and used pointers */
    
    lines = malloc (allocated * sizeof *lines); /* allocate initial pointer(s) */
    
    if (lines == NULL) {                        /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-lines");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    while (fgets (buffer, MAXC, fp)) {          /* read each line from file */
        size_t len;                             /* variable to hold line-length */
        if (used == allocated) {                /* is pointer reallocation needed */
            /* always realloc to a temporary pointer to avoid memory leak if
             * realloc fails returning NULL.
             */
            void *tmp = realloc (lines, 2 * allocated * sizeof *lines);
            if (!tmp) {                         /* validate EVERY reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-lines");
                break;                          /* lines before failure still good */
            }
            lines = tmp;                        /* assign reallocted block to lines */
            allocated *= 2;                     /* update no. of allocated pointers */
        }
        buffer[(len = strcspn (buffer, "\n"))] = 0;     /* trim \n, save length */
        
        lines[used] = malloc (len + 1);         /* allocate storage for line */
        if (!lines[used]) {                     /* validate EVERY allocation */
            perror ("malloc-lines[used]");
            break;
        }
        
        memcpy (lines[used], buffer, len + 1);  /* copy buffer to lines[used] */
        used++;                                 /* increment used no. of pointers */
    }
    *n = used;              /* update value at address provided by n */
    
    /* can do final realloc() here to resize exactly to used no. of pointers */
    
    return lines;           /* return pointer to allocated block of pointers */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char **lines;       /* pointer to allocated block of pointers and lines */
    size_t n;           /* number of lines read */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    lines = readfile (fp, &n);
    
    if (fp != stdin)    /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    if (!lines) {       /* validate readfile() return */
        fputs ("error: no lines read from file.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {            /* loop outputting all lines read */
        puts (lines[i]);
        free (lines[i]);                        /* don't forget to free lines */
    }
    free (lines);                               /* and free pointers */
    
    return 0;
}
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi! I'm really glad for this detailed approach and I love all the insights about it. I'm processing it right now! Theres a whole lot to process oof I'm still a noob on C but I'll try to sponge out all about what you said. But our teacher explicitly said to use a function that goes `char *freadline(FILE *fp)`. I know its pretty sad but yeah there is that. I'm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a fine till the last line, you can simply use `getc()`. It returns EOF when end of file is reached or it fails to read. So, if using `getc()`, to make sure the end of file is reached, it's better to use `feof()`, which returns  a non-zero value if end of file is reached, else 0.

Example :-

```
int main()
{
  FILE *fp = fopen("story.txt", "r");
 int ch = getc(fp);
  while (ch != EOF) 
  {
    /* display contents of file on screen */ 
    putchar(ch); 

    ch = getc(fp);
   }

    if (feof(fp))
       printf("\n End of file reached.");
    else 
       printf("\nError while reading!");
    fclose(fp);
  
    getchar();
    return 0;
  }
```

you can also `fgets()`, below is the example :-

```
#define MAX_LEN 256

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("story.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
      perror("Failed: "); //prints a descriptive error message to stderr.
      return 1;
     }

    char buffer[MAX_LEN];
    // -1 to allow room for NULL terminator for really long string
    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN - 1, fp))
    {
        // Remove trailing newline
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
     }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

alternatively,

```
int main() {

int MAX_LEN = 255;
char buffer[MAX_LEN];

FILE *fp = fopen("story.txt", "r");

while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN, fp)) {
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

For more details, refer [C read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: Hi! This approach is great and I actually tried a variation of it! Just that our teacher strictly said that we should use `char * freadline(FILE *fp)` as a function where we use `fgets` :(

Comment: additionally, he requires us to allocate the same exact memory as the size is supposed to be

Comment: I hope you realize that using `fgets` does not guarantee that you read a line after it returns. If a line is longer than `MAX_LEN`, your method using fgets will print multiple newlines before reaching the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong and it's very likely that it will generate an endless loop. I'll explain why using the original code and inline comments:

```
char *freadline(FILE *fp){
    int i;

    // This part attempts to count the number of characters
    // in the whole file by reading char-by-char until EOF is set
    for(i = 0; !feof(fp); i++){
        getc(fp);
    }

    // Here EOF is set

    // This returns to the start and clears EOF
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Here EOF is cleared

    char *pBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*i);

    // Here you read a line, i.e. you read characters until (and including) the
    // first newline in the file.
    pBuffer = fgets(pBuffer, i, fp);

    // Here EOF is still cleared as you only read the first line of the file
    
    return pBuffer;
}
```

So in `main` when you do

```
while(!feof(fp)){
    ...
}
```

you have an endless loop as `feof` is false. Your program will print the same line again and again and you have memory leaks as you never call `free(pInput)`.

So you need to redesign your code. Read what `fgets` do, e.g. here https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html

Comment: Yes yes I completely understand but I dont know where else to reset the file to the place where its supposed to be without using fseek or rewind

Comment: @arpi314 Well, the problem is the first part. You don't need it. There is no need to count all chars in the whole file. Use `fgets` only

Answer (score 1):

A number of issues to address:

- Using `fgets` does not guarantee that you read a line after the function returns. So if you really want to check whether you've read a complete line, check the number of characters in the returned string, and also check for the presence of a new-line character at the end of the string.
- Your use of `fseek` is interesting here because what it does is to tell the stream pointer to go back to the start of the file, and start reading from there. This means that after the first time the `freadline` function is called, you will continue reading the first byte from the file each time.
- Lastly, your program is hoarding memory like a greedy baby! You never free any of those allocations you did!

With that being said, here is an improved `freadline` implementation:

```
char *freadline(FILE *fp) {
    /* initializations */
    char    buf[BUFSIZ + 1];
    char   *pBuffer;
    size_t  size = 0, tmp_size;

    /* fgets returns NULL when it reaches EOF, so our loop is conditional
     * on that
     */
    while (fgets (buf, BUFSIZ + 1, fp) != NULL) {
        tmp_size = strlen (buf);
        size += tmp_size;
        if (tmp_size != BUFSIZ || buf[BUFSIZ] == '\n')
            break;
    }

    /* after breaking from loop, check that size is not zero.
     * this should only happen if we reach EOF, so return NULL
     */
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;

    /* Allocate memory for the line plus one extra for the null byte */
    pBuffer = malloc (size + 1);

    /* reads the contents of the file into pBuffer */
    if (size <= BUFSIZ) {
        /* Optimization: use memcpy rather than reading 
         * from disk if the line is small enough
         */
        memcpy (pBuffer, buf, size);
    } else {
        fseek (fp, ftell(fp) - size, SEEK_SET);
        fread (pBuffer, 1, size, fp);
    }
    pBuffer[size] = '\0'; /* set the null terminator byte */
    return pBuffer; /* remember to free () this when you are done! */
}
```

This way will not need the additional call to `feof` (which is often a hit and miss), and instead relies on what `fgets` returns to determine if we have reached the end of file.

With these changes, it should be enough to change `main` to:

```
int main() {

    FILE *fp = fopen("story.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error!");
    }else{
        char *pInput;
        /* here we just keep reading until a NULL string is returned */
        for (pInput = freadline(fp); pInput != NULL; pInput = freadline(fp))) {
            printf("%s", pInput); // output
            free (pInput);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, can i ask what `BUFSIZ` does?

Comment: Can I also ask a detailed approach through each line? I'm kind of a noobie when it comes to C.

Comment: I also tried running your code using a file with 3 lines but it did not print out the other two. I am confused.

Comment: @arpi314 yea that's what I get for writing code before I go to sleep and not testing it. I think the problem was that I may have not been terminating the returned strings with `\0`. I have also added comments. As for what [`BUFSIZ`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/BUFSIZ/) is, I wouldn't get too caught up on this. I just used it because it is a macro that exists in `stdio.h` and it is non zero. It has other uses WRT buffered streams, but that's a different topic.