# Issues with 'read' system function

Tags: c

I was writing a programm which must read a word, which is separated from others by a `' '` or `\n`, from a file (I decided to use `'read'` system function for it) and faced up an issue with it.

In particular, as it is written in manual, `'read'` must return `0` when there is nothing else to read (`EOF` is reached), but in my case it returns `\n` (I checked the `ASCII` code of returned symbol and it's `10`which is of `\n` and checked my program a number of times and it always returns the same). Here's the code

```
char *read_word_from_file(int fd, int *flag)
{
    int i = 0;
    char ch, *buf = NULL;
    if (!read(fd, &ch, 1)) {    //file is empty
        *flag = 1;
        return NULL;
    }
    while (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n') {
        if (!(buf = (char *) realloc(buf, i + 1))) goto mem_err;
        buf[i++] = ch;
        if (!(read(fd, &ch, 1))) {
            *flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';
    return buf;
mem_err:
    perror("realloc");
    exit(1);
}
```

(`flag` variable is used to indicate the `EOF` for the outer function, which calls this one) So, my question is "is such behavior is normal, or I made a mistake somewhere?"

`P.S. - Off-topic question, how do you make a part of text(a single word) shadowed like a code samples?`

Comment: Did you try `fdopen` + `fseek` + `fscanf` or `fgetc`

Comment: to answer the offtopic: use backticks, like this `code` word.

Comment: read() reads a newline because there was a newline in the input. What is the problem?

Comment: The value in `ch` is *not* the return value. If you want the return value, then you need something like `retval = read(fd, &ch, 1);`. The value 10 in `ch` is there from the previous successful call to `read`. `read` doesn't change the value in `ch` when it fails.

Comment: @user3121023 It returns 0 when there's nothing left to read.

Comment: @user3386109 I printed ch after each of the `read` calls and the value does change, because i have some letters before EOF in my file and it still '\n' which is stored in `ch` after the last call

Comment: @Jens I didn't understand what input you are talking about, sorry

Comment: read should be used something like bytes_read = read(fd, &ch, 1); if ( bytes_read > 0) { check ch} else error

Comment: @VladislavKolesnikov It seems you are confused about where read() returns what information. In `retval = read(fd, buffer, count)` the input characters from the file descriptor are stored in buffer; the return value from read is `retval`. If retval is < 0, an error occurred; if retval is 0, there's nothing more to read; if retval > 0, that many characters were copied to buffer. The retval is never 10 in your case, since you always ask for 1 byte.

Comment: @Jens I never said that retval is 10, I said that the ascii code of the character stored in the ch after the call is ten

Comment: @VladislavKolesnikov OK. And I said that this is because there was a newline read from the file descriptor. I don't understand your problem. If read() reads a 10, then there was a 10 in the input. There is nothing surprising happening here. Or do you look at ch even if read() didn't read anything (retval != 1)? You shouldn't. The buffer only contains meaningful content when read returns > 0. Maybe you could tell us how you open the fd and what input you provide? That would be very helpful.

Comment: @Jens well, I just can't understand why after the last char in my file (let it be M) does 'read' reads 1 character into ch (changes it from M to '\n'), returns 1 (number of bytes read) when my file doesnt contain any characters after M (including newlines). I open my file simply with an 'open' function with O_RDONLY flag

Comment: @VladislavKolesnikov How do you know there's no newline in the file? What is the file size (`ls -l file`)? What is its contents (`od -c file`)?

Comment: @Jens oh, 'od -c' shows that there is newline at the end, though if opening it with gedit it seems that there isnt any. Now can i change my origin question to why is it in this way?

Comment: @VladislavKolesnikov Why is what in which way? gedit simply doesn't show newlines in files. Why is there a newline in your file? Depends on how you created that file. If you used for example `puts("M");` then you should understand that puts() adds a newline. If you created it with an editor, you should understand that editors usually write complete lines ending in a newline.

Comment: @Jens well, if you say its all because of editors, thanks, then its clear now. Thank you very much

Comment: @VladislavKolesnikov, you don't see `\n` character in gedit, because it is a **control character**. It's invisible, except for the effect it produces on the terminal (or in the file) to separate lines from each other.  But they are there.  Other control characters of interest are `\r` (13, carry return, makes printing continue at first column in same line), `\a` (7, bell, makes terminal emit a tone), `\t` (9, tab, makes printing continue at the next tab stop). etc.  See `ascii(7)` for a description fo control characters.

Comment: Read [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) man page. It can fail then return -1. You should use the return count, and for efficiency reasons, you'll better read into a buffer of several kilobytes (e.g. 4kbytes to 1Mbytes). Calling `read` once per byte is *very inefficient*. BTW, why can't you use *stdio* functions? They are buffering!

Comment: Also, `realloc` ing every time is very inefficient. Consider using some `newsize = 4*oldsize/3+10;` scheme and have some "geometric" progression.

Comment: Consider using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gedit simply doesn't show newlines in files. Why is there a newline in your file? Depends on how you created that file. If you used for example `puts("M");` then you should understand that puts() adds a newline. If you created it with an editor, you should understand that editors usually write complete lines ending in a newline.
                    – Jens