# Reading a string, char[] until end of line C

Tags: c, linux

I need to read a file name, but I want my code working for names contains space.
How to read until end of line from keyboard?

My code:

```
#define szoveghosz 256
//....
char bemenet[szoveghosz]; 
fgets (bemenet,sizeof(bemenet),stdin);
```

Comment: Please describe how your code is broken, ie what result you get and what you expect instead (it looks ok at a first glance). It would also be helpful to have identifiers in your code in *english language*.

Comment: for me if i want to read  a text from keyboard it saves in "bemenet" array until the first space.

Comment: Consider using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), then parse manually the line which has been read.

Comment: BTW, with a `;` in the `#define szoveghosz 256;` line your code should not compile. So remove that semicolon.

Comment: @zarnilord I don't believe you.

Comment: fgets is right, assuming you can put a reasonably small (eg 1000) bound on maximum acceptable input.

Comment: only consider `getline()` if you only target systems conforming to POSIX.1-2008 and later (ok for linux, not ok for windows, for example)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: the question is tagged Linux

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, it is, but as the presented snippet is portable standard-c so far, I think this is worth mentioning ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read *carefully* the documentation of [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) (which might be locally available on your Linux computer with `man fgets`)

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream
>          and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after
>          an `EOF` or a newline.  If a newline is read, *it is stored* into the
>          buffer.  A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last
>          character in the buffer.

As documented, `fgets` will (when possible) keep the newline character. You probably want to remove it. So I recommend coding instead

```
 memset (bemenet, 0, sizeof(bemenet)); // clear the buffer
 if (fgets(bemenet, sizeof(bemenet), stdin)) {
    char *eol = strchr(bemenet, '\n');
    if (eol) 
       *eol = '\0';
    /// do appropriate things on bemenet
 }
```

See also [strchr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) & [memset(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html)

But as I commented, on Linux and POSIX systems, [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) is preferable (because it is allocating dynamically an arbitrarily long line). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108).

Notice that (in principle) a filename could contain a newline (but in most cases, you can forget that possibility). See also [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) & [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) and [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) and [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html).