# Reading line by line using fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read a file with 3 lines:

The first one with strings, second with a number and the third with strings again.

Example:

Line 1: bird toy book computer water

Line 2:  2

Line 3: toy water

I have this code, that reads a file, word by word storing them in the word array, and then putting the word into the words 2d array.

```
char words [5][50];
char word [50];
int i,j;
j = 0;

while( (fscanf(file, "%s", word))!=EOF ){
    for(i = 0; i<50; i++){
        if(word[i] != NULL){
            words[j][i] = word[i];
        } else{
            break;
        }
    }
    j++;

}
```

it's working, but it reads all the lines, i want a way to just do this process for the first line, and then store the second line into a int variable and the third line into another 2d array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read more about [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). It is *not suitable* to read *line by line*.

Consider instead reading every line with [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) or even better (on POSIX) with [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108)), then parse each line perhaps with [sscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Its return value (the count of scanned items given from `sscanf` etc...) could be useful to test (and you might also want to use `%n` in the scan control format string; as [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) commented, read also about `%ms` assignment-allocation modifier, at least on POSIX systems, see Linux [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html)).

BTW, hard-coding limits like `50` for your word length is bad taste (and not [robust](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Semantics)). Consider perhaps using more systematically [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) (using [`malloc`, `free` and friends](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory)) and pointers, perhaps using sometimes [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) in some of your `struct`-s

Comment: If you've got support for POSIX [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html), the `m` 'assignment-allocation' modifier is useful in `%ms`.  It dynamically allocates the space needed to hold the string that's read — but the `sscanf()` argument is a `char **`, not a `char *`.  Not all Unix-like systems support it though — specifically, macOS Sierra 10.12.5 does not, nor do the prior Mac OS X versions.