# Is There any way to read Full name from a text file with other information in c?

Tags: c

Actually I am trying to solve a problem using C file management where I have to read a text file where are some data given of multiple student. The problem is with their name. I thought I can solve that problem with first name and last name but then I figured out that some of name are multiple word more than two. So is their any way to solve that full name issue?

The text file is in txt format.

```
1. 1330273 Sajjad Kashem 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
2. 1520297 A. S. M. Irfan 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried already?

Comment: From the sample data in your question, it looks like each line in the text file has the same structure, namely a number followed by a dot followed by a single space followed by a number followed by a single space followed by the full name followed by a space and finally a series of nine binary digits where each digit is separated by a single space. Seems simple enough to do with function `fscanf()`

Answer (score 2):

If the next character after name is 0 or 1, you could try this approach:

```c
sscanf(line, "%d. %d %[^01]%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, name, &c, &d, &e, &f ...);
```

Don't forget to strip `name`: last character can be space.

Comment: but it stops the loop and show only one student's data, i mean same data. like

`1. 1330273 Sajjad Kashem 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
1. 1330273 Sajjad Kashem 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0`

Comment: Yes, it's a problem. You can read file line by line like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44862617/11914501) and then use `sscanf` instead of `fscanf` with the similar signature.