# C language: how to consider new line with scanf

Tags: c

So i have program that get numbers from user in single line for example:

```
2 1 2 3 4
```

The first number: 2 mean that the output should be matrix with 2 rows and 2 columns:

```
1 2
3 4
```

So this is how i am populate my aray:

```
int dim;
scanf("%d", &dim);
int *m = (int *)malloc(dim* dim* sizeof(int))

for (r = 0; r < dim; ++r)
{
    for (c = 0; c < dim; ++c)
    {
        scanf("%d", &m[dim * r + c]);
    }
}
```

Now i want to add some value check, in case the user input start with `2` the next input should contain 4 number (`2²`) in a single line so in case the input is `2 1 2 3` i want to print error message but my problem is that after this input the `scanf` just ignored from the new line and wait.

Comment: scanf returns the number of items found. All your calls to scanf should return a 1 since they only read one value. If they ever return a 0, then the scanf has failed and there wasn't enough data.

Comment: You want to call malloc after the first scanf, otherwise dim won't have any value.

Comment: The malloc call order fixed but how can i check the user input ?

Comment: I've already answered that.

Comment: @DanaYeger: Please don't comment your own question, but do edit it. BTW, *do-my-homework* or *fix-my-code* questions are **off-topic** on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) is organized in *lines*, you could read each line entirely (probably with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108) or else with `fgets`) then parse that line appropriately in memory (keeping some internal pointer inside it, and using [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) with its end pointer, or [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) with `%n`). BTW what *exactly* defines a line is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific (Windows vs Linux vs MacOSX have different definitions and line terminators).

If you are not sure that the input is organized in lines, you'll use standard [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages) techniques (e.g some [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)), probably with a single token of look ahead.

In all cases, you'll better **specify** on paper **your [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format)**. A simple [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation is a good specification for most parsers.

Your current code is wrong, because you don't test against failure of [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).  You need to test its returned scanned item count. BTW, it is also wrong to use `malloc` without testing its failure, and you probably should use `calloc` not  `malloc` because you should prefer zeroed memory.

Notice that `scanf` with `%d` (or better yet, `" %d"`) is skipping spaces, including newline characters ending input lines. In other words, your `scanf` don't care about *lines*, as you say you want to.

Compile your code with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and use the debugger `gdb` to run it step by step and understand what is happening. Spend more time in reading documentation (notably of [standard C functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c), and of your software tools: [compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), [debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), ... that you would use on the command line).

---

BTW, [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) are complex (virtual) devices. On my Linux system, they could be line buffered by the kernel's [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline). You might read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and consider using [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) or [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (if you are *sure* to read from the terminal). Using `fgets`, `getline` and other [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) functions is enough only if you are just reading from `stdin` and don't care about [pseudo-terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) vs [redirections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) or command [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)). See also [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html).

<sup>(the last above paragraph is specific for Linux, and probably not for newbies. IMHO terminals are very complex, once you dive into details.)</sup>

Comment: No, the input should be in a single line.

Comment: Unless you know that all the input will be passed in one line there is no way to know that the rest of the input comes from the stdin. Simply because user can change her mind just after you call scanf.

Comment: i want to count the number and for example if the line start with 2 thats mean that i need more 4 numbers and if i have 3 and new line i want to pring error message

Comment: **You** definitely **should spend hours *reading* documentation** (notably of `malloc`, `calloc`, `scanf`, `getline`, `fgets`). We won't do your homework.

Comment: @DanaYeger - the `"%d"` *format specifier* will skip *leading whitespace*. (a `'\n'` is *whitespace*) So what he is saying is it does not matter if all your input is on one line, or if it is on 5 separate lines -- `scanf ("%d",...` will read an integer and then skip all spaces and newlines and read the next value.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: nitpicking, I think (but I am not entirely sure) that `scanf("%d",` will first skip spaces -including newlines- and then read one integer (not in the opposite order).

Comment: Hehe, that's one I had to prove to myself -- but it does. Example `while (scanf ("%d", &i) == 1) printf ("%d\n", i);` and feed it `printf " 1\n \n2 3\n4" | ./prog`. It will in fact skip `spaces` and `newlines` in any order (even multiple `newlines`) without the leading space (e.g. `" %d"`) in the format string. `:)`

Comment: So from all  the comments what is the best way to read single line with numbers and from here continue ?

Comment: i just very confuse now

Comment: I don't know. If you care only about stdin, use `getline` or `fgets` and then parse that line. If you really want an editable line from a terminal on Linux -not just from stdin-, consider `readline`, which BTW is really simple to use. I have no idea if you want your program to support redirections and pipelines. As I explained in my last paragraph, terminals are *really* complex. But your *question* is confusing and your code is wrong (every outside function e.g. `scanf` or `malloc` can fail, and you should test that!)