# Is there a decent way to replace a string within a file with another word in C?

Tags: c, file, string.h

Is there a way to replace a string within a file with another word in C?
I realized that the only way (maybe) possible is to rewrite the first file on a temp file with the appropriate changes.
The problem is that by doing this I am forced to do both a reading and a writing of the same file (it is not so optimized). Is there a way to make string changes without creating a new file? And if yes, how could i do it?

Comment: You can only do it directly if the strings are the same size. There's no way to insert or delete directly in a file.

Comment: 'by doing this I am forced to do both a reading and a writing of the same file' no.  You read the input file, write the output file, delete the input file, rename the output file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace a string `aa` by some string `bbb` of different byte length (not the same as the UTF-8 character length, see [utf8everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)) you need to have a temporary file, so you temporarily need twice the disk space.
BTW, you might need to specify what exactly a *word* is for you (think of how words are ending, or are separated; what about [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)?).

If both original and replacement strings have the same *byte* length (e.g. `aa` replaced by `cc` but not by `çà`), you could do the replacement in place.

If the file size is small (less than a few gigabytes), you could afford reading it *entirely in heap memory* (read about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), use `malloc` and `free`), [`remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove) the original file, and write (e.g. with `fwrite` or `fprintf`) the new one from memory.

On current laptops or desktops, most files are small enough to fit in memory (e.g. because they are smaller than a gigabyte), but not all. You could have a file of a terabyte, on some large enough disk (provided your disk partition and file system allows that).

**Read more about C [`stdio`  input output functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)**. There is no way to  insert or remove bytes "in the middle of" or "inside" a file, only at its end.

If the file is textual (not binary), you might read it line by line (using [getline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108) if you have it, or else *carefully* using [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and handling line overflow appropriately) and process every line in a loop. You could then assume that each line fits in memory (e.g. is less than a gigabyte).

If you are required to be able to process a huge file containing a single terabyte line, you need to think more about how to do that (e.g. read about [finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) and/or do your processing in chunks).

If such replacements are a common operation that you want to do efficiently, you might think of some different (and more "efficient") way of keeping your data on the disk, perhaps using indexed files à la [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/manual/gdbm.html), or databases à la [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/).

Comment: That relates to the fundamental theorem of atavistic selection on Stack Overflow -- a highly advanced topic.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: There is a theorem like that? Suspicious. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you need to include the string header...eg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  string proverb {"A nod is as good as a wink to a blind horse"};
  string sentence {"It's bath time!"};    // lol
  proverb.replace(38, 5, sentence, 5, 3);
 ......etc
```

this replaces horse with bat
or

```
proverb.replace(0, 43, sentence, 0, 15);
```

to replace the string...play around with it theirs probably other ways

Comment: The question is about C. Not C++.

Comment: well it doesn't really matter when your using visual studio

Comment: Sorry but it's C only.