# Is there a way to control when(or where) gets() or fgets() functions start taking Input?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

first I would to like to mention that I am new to programming.

I am trying to write a program that takes in multiple inputs, last of which is a string, when I use the gets() or fgets() functions they read the input from the after previous input finishes. So for example:

```
printf("Enter decimal:\n");
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("Enter string:\n");
gets(str[100]);
printf("%d\n%s",x,str);
```

Sample Input/Output:

```
Enter decimal:
3\n            //If I change line after inputting the decimal the program continues as if it already read the string
Enter string:
3
```

However If the input is as follows:

```
Enter decimal:
3 Hello World\n            
Enter string:
3  
Hello World
```

I suppose this is how the gets() and fgets() functions work but is there a way to control it in sense or is there an alternative (The string that would be inputted can be very long
)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gets` is dangerous and deprecated. Don't use it at all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: Be warned that `gets()` is deprecated and insecure. Never use it. `fgets()` is okay to use.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please try to improve it.

Comment: `gets()` is not only deprecated, but C11 ***removes*** it from the language.  It persists in modern C implementations only as an extension for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Next time, provide some [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `gets()` is obsolete and risky because the destination array size is not passed to the function, so it cannot prevent a buffer overrun if user input is too long. It has been finally removed from the latest version of the C Standard. Use `fgets()` instead.
- mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` is error prone as `scanf()` leaves part of user input pending, such as the newline typed by the user after the number, and this pending input will be read by `fgets()`, which in this particular case will return immediately because the pending newline is precisely what `fgets()` expects to end its input.

I recommend using `fgets()` to read input line by line and use `sscanf` to convert the input to the expected types. It has the extra advantage of allowing easy error recovery.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[100];
    int x;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter decimal: ");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            return 1;
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &x) == 1)
            break;
        printf("Invalid input: not a number\n");
    }
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter string:\n");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            return 1;
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the trailing newline if any
        if (buf[0] != '\0')
            break;
        printf("Invalid input: empty string\n");
    }
    printf("%d\n%s\n", x, buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read more about [C standard IO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). Notice that `gets` was deprecated and dangereous but is now removed from the C standard. You should never use it (and please, forget that it has existed). Probably you mean `fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)` instead of your call to the disappeared `gets`, assuming that `str` is some *array* of `char`s, e.g. declared as `char str[100];`.

You might read an entire line with `fgets` (or even [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108)) then parse that buffer, perhaps using [sscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (or [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), or [strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), or using your own [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) & [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques).

Notice that `sscanf` (like `fscanf` and `scanf`) returns a scanned item count (and accepts `%n`) but don't care about end-of-lines. You need to use that.

Read documentation of the functions you are using very carefully.

When reading from a genuine file, you could also reposition inside it using [fseek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) (with [ftell](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell)). That won't work on the console (since the terminal is generally non-[seekable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output#fseek)).

Perhaps you could use some [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) related libraries (such as [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or [readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)). These are not in the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and might not be available on your operating system (but on Linux and some others OSes, you have them).

Remember that your stdin is not always a terminal. Think of [redirections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) and [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)).

Read also [*How to Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Be sure to compile your code with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)).

If you are on Linux or some POSIX operating system, be aware that *stdin* is related to the [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) 0 (named `STDIN_FILENO`). So if you want to wait till some input is available, consider using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) on that file descriptor.

PS. Your question is really unclear. I can just guess what you want to do.... Consider improving it after having read more documentation...

Comment: Thank you, the sources you provided are very helpful. Since I am new programming I am still not quite familiar with the technical wording, I will be sure to read more!