# How to backup strings in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, c-strings, strcpy

How can I back up the string in its original form? I'm using strncpy() but, however when I try to print the sentence the original text is altered.
Here is an example: if I entered "This is a sample text" for gets and ask to print the sentence, the console prints "TTTTs is a  ample ttxt". Can someone tell how to make it so that the sentenceBackup variable has a backup and the sentence is correctly displayed as entered.

```
    //String variable to contain the user input.
    char sentence[] = "";
    char sentenceBackup[] ="";

    //this variable tracks the size of the user input.
    int sentenceLength;

    //ask the user forsinput
    printf("Enter a free formed sentence that needs to be sorted: \n");

    //accept the user entry into sentence.
    //scanf is deprecated since C11.
    gets(sentence);

    // keep a backup for further operation.
    strncpy(sentenceBackup, sentence, findLength(sentence));


    //display the sentence entered.
    printf("The sentence is : %s\n", sentence);
```

Ps: If I take off the strncpy() method, the source text,i.e sentence variable is correctly displayed.

Comment: When you declare an array in C without specifying the array size, C assumes that it was intended to be the same size as its initializer.  In your case, 1 `char` long.  Try giving your array declarations a large size, like `[2048]`; otherwise the second character written to `sentenceBackup` likely overwrites the first character of `sentence`.  Think of the arrays as being adjacent in memory and only 1 char long, each...where does the second char written by your `strncpy` go?

Comment: `char sentence[] = ""` is too small to take input from `gets(sentence);`

Comment: Why the comment `scanf is deprecated in C11`? It is not (see §7.21.6.4 of [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). Of course `gets` is absent from C11 (which has `fgets` in §7.21.7.2) so you should [not](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) use it. Please **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: BTW, your question has no [MCVE]. It should has a *complete* program. That is another reason to improve your question

Answer (score 2):

1. The size of `sentence` is insufficient to hold the input.
2. Second, `gets` is deprecated, so do not use it. From this [online C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets):

   > **The gets() function does not perform bounds checking, therefore this function is extremely vulnerable to buffer-overflow attacks**. It cannot be used safely (unless the program runs in an environment which restricts what can appear on stdin). For this reason, **the function has been deprecated in the third corrigendum to the C99 standard and removed altogether in the C11 standard**. fgets() and gets_s() are the recommended replacements. **Never use gets().**

Comment: Also the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) does not even *mention* `gets`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: [N1570: footnote 404 (Annex K.3.5.4.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note404): _The `gets_s` function, unlike the historical `gets` function, …_  Also, at the other end of the document, [Foreword §6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp6): _removed the `gets` function (`<stdio.h>`)_  But I grant you, these are not exactly major references, and certainly not definitions of what the archaic `gets()` function does.

Comment: And the index of n1570 don't mention `gets`

Answer (score 0):

If [using `getline`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108) or [`strdup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strndup.3.html) is acceptable for you, then use them!

If you are not allowed to use them, you should at least [heap-allocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) the strings (with `calloc`, but don't forget the extra byte for the ending <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte) and don't forget to `free` them later. Of course you need to "backup" explicitly (by appropriately copying the original string).

If heap allocation is not allowed, be sure to declare large enough buffers. I would suggest at least 128 bytes.

Please look into some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site (study the documentation of every function that you use) and later refer to the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). You'll see that `gets` is no more part of C and is forbidden since dangerous. Use `fgets` at least (and preferably `getline`).

Compile your code with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve it to get no warnings at all. The use the debugger (`gdb` or something else) and read [*How To Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Be aware that [UTF-8 is used everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) in 2018. So `strlen` don't give the number of characters (since a character like `Ê` or `∀` needs several bytes in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)), only the byte length.